# Determine the duration of a journey in light/dark

Tags: php, time

I am building a application that needs to determine the number of minutes that a journey is spent in daylight and/or darkness.

I have access to: the lat/long of both the place of departure and the destination, as well as the datetime for both as well (and therefore the total duration and rough distance).

I have been able to use PHP's sun funcs to found out sunrise/sets, however I am looking for a way to actually find a way to determine the proportion of day/night (i.e you can start in the day and end in the dark, so at some point in between it turns to "night", and I need to find that position)

Any help most appreciated.

```
$originSunrise = self::sunrise($flight->date_depart, $airportDepart->airportLat, $airportDepart->airportLong);
$originSunset = self::sunset($flight->date_depart, $airportDepart->airportLat, $airportDepart->airportLong);

$destinationSunrise = self::sunrise($flight->date_arrive, $airportArrive->airportLat, $airportArrive->airportLong);
$destinationSunset = self::sunset($flight->date_arrive, $airportArrive->airportLat, $airportArrive->airportLong);
```

Where

```
public static function sunrise(Carbon $date, $latitude, $longitude){
    $timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
    return Carbon::createFromTimestamp(date_sunrise($timestamp, SUNFUNCS_RET_TIMESTAMP, $latitude, $longitude));
}

public static function sunset(Carbon $date, $latitude, $longitude){
    $timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
    return Carbon::createFromTimestamp(date_sunset($timestamp, SUNFUNCS_RET_TIMESTAMP, $latitude, $longitude));
}
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Share you code please

Comment: I feel like this would be impossible to determine without knowing the exact route of travel, and without assuming a 100% constant rate of travel.

Comment: _“but this doesn't allow you to work out the proportion of time actually spent in day/night”_ - well of course those functions don’t do that for you, that’s just too specific a requirement … What did you come up with so far? I’d maybe start by putting those sunrise and -down times from your travel start date all the way to the end into an array ... then you can loop over that, and calculate the difference between the current entry and the previous one. And depending on whether with the current entry the change was from night to day or vice versa, you add that difference to the according time.

Comment: Agreed with @Patrick, even though airplanes (which are apparently involved here) have a relatively constant rate of travel, their choice of route can drastically alter when the day/night terminator is crossed. At best you'll get a rough approximation.